# How to decide if a bivariate rational function is bounded around the origin

Tags: polynomials, algorithms

If $F(x)$ is a rational function (with rational coefficients, say) of a single variable $x$, then $F$ is bounded in $\mathbb R$ around $0$ iff the degree of $F(\frac{1}{x})$ is nonpositive.

I wonder if there is a similar (or just slightly more complicated) criterion for bivariate rational functions, $F(x,y)$ ; I am looking for an algorithm that decides in finite time if $F(x,y)$ is bounded in ${\mathbb R}^2$ around $(0,0)$.

My thoughts : (1) If the denominator of $F$ is nonzero at $(0,0)$, then $F$ is well-defined and continuous there and therefore automatically bounded around $(0,0)$. We may thus assume that the denominator vanishes at $(0,0)$.

(2) Similarly, if the denominator vanishes but not the numerator, then $F$ goes to infinity on some curves tending to $(0,0)$, so that $F$ is not bounded. We may thus assume that both numerator and denominator vanish at $(0,0)$ ; a typical example would be $F(x,y)=\frac{x^{b_1}+y^{b_2}}{x^{a_1}+y^{a_2}}$ where $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2$ are integers $\geq 1$.

(3) A necessary condition is that $F(t^i,t^j),F(t^i,0),F(0,t^j)$ all be bounded around $t=0$ for any $(i,j)\in{\mathbb N}^2$. Unfortunately, that makes infinitely many checks to test and further it is not clear if the condition is also sufficient.

**Update 04/05/2023** As noted by fedja in a comment below, the tests in (3) are not sufficient, as shown by $f(x,y)=\frac{x^6}{(y-x-x^2)^2+x^8+y^8}$. Since $f(t,t+t^2)\sim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{2t^2}$ we see that $f$ is unbounded, on the other hand it is easy to see that all the tests in (3) are satisfied by $f$.

Comment: In $\mathbb R^2$ or in $\mathbb C^2$? Also, do you have any additional information about the numerator and the denominator that may arise in your setting, or they are just completely arbitrary rational functions with rational coefficients?

Comment: @fedja My concern is with ${\mathbb R}^2$ (although I presume boundedness over ${\mathbb R}$ is equivalent to boundedness over $\mathbb C$) and yes, the rational functions are completely arbitrary  in ${\mathbb Q}(x,y)$.

Comment: Nope, it isn't: $\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ is bounded near $0$ in $\mathbb R^2$, but not in $\mathbb C^2$. The real case is harder :-(

Comment: Theoretically, it should be feasible within the rational arithmetic: if the fraction is $P/Q$, then you want to find out if there is $K\in \mathbb N$ such that $F_K=KQ^2-P^2\ge 0$ near the origin, which can be checked by looking at small circles around the origin and counting roots of $F_K$ there using the rational parameterization $x=K^{-1}\frac {2t}{1+t^2}, y=\pm K^{-1}\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$, $t\in[-1,1]$. What is hard here is to figure out how high in $K$ one has to go to come to a decisive conclusion either way. In principle, you can keep it as a free parameter and run Sturm (contd)

Comment: In the end all Sturm signs (as $K\to+\infty$) will become clear, so you'll be in good shape (and the degree does not depend on $K$, so the number of steps is fixed). But honestly I wouldn't try to implement that myself (one has to implement integer arithmetic with arbitrary size of integers first. And then polynomials in $t$ with coefficients in $\mathbb Q(K)$. Brrr-r-r...).

Comment: Just curious: How high degrees and what size of integer (multiply everything by the common denominator) coefficients are you shooting for? Also, I'm an idiot: squares (or triangles) are just as good as circles and yield smaller degrees. OK, give me some non-trivial example with low degree and I'll see how that works :-)

Comment: @fedja Thing is, I have trouble finding a non-trivial example ; every $F$ I've tried turns out to be either unbounded on some $(t^i,t^j)$ as in (3), or can be shown to be bounded by writing it as a sum of products of terms of the form $G(x),H(y)$ (univariates in either variable) or $\frac{(xy)^{\frac{a+b}{2}}}{x^a+y^b}$.

Comment: Come on! Of course, $\frac{x^6}{(y-x-x^2)^2+x^8+y^8}$ is trivially unbounded, but it is bounded on each of your curves and even has non-vanishing denominator :-). How about the sizes of degrees and coefficients in your application?

Comment: @fedja I have updated the original question with your counterexample. My application is about finding a simple description of the fourtuples of integers $(i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4)$ such that $\frac{x^{i_1}y^{i_2}}{(x^2+y^2)^{i_3}(x^4+y^2)^{i_4}}$ is bounded near $(0,0)$, so at least in this initial form it involves arbitrary large degrees.

Comment: How does it square with "*and yes, the rational functions are completely arbitrary in $\mathbb Q(x,y)$*)? The problem you are asking about now should be easily solvable. Is it all you care about?

Comment: @fedja My motivation started with the application I gave but I find the more general question also interesting, in fact more interesting, which is why I asked about the more general problem here first (I may ask another MSE question about the application in the future). So if you're wondering whether an answer only solving that "easily solvable" special case would get the bounty, the answer is no.

Comment: Nope, it is not about "bounties", it is just about what you *really need*. The extent to which I bother to *write* an answer once I figure something out depends on whether something is just idle curiosity or a "missing tool" (the extent to which I am willing to *think* of the question doesn't). I have already described a finite algorithm that works in general but I'd rather not try to implement it myself if you don't really need it to run. "Easily solvable" was an euphemism: the problem is "trivial": just consider several cases according to which term dominates in each parentheses. :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145122/discussion-between-ewan-delanoy-and-fedja).

Comment: OK :- )                 $\phantom{uuuuuuuuu}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, here goes, as promised. Apologies for the delay.

Let $F(x,y)=\frac{P(x,y)}{Q(x,y)}$. The boundedness of $F$ near $(0,0)$ is equivalent to its boundedness near $(0,0)$ in each region $R_j$, $j=1,2,3,4$ where $R_1={(x,y):x>0,|y|\le x}$ and the other three $R_j$ are obtaine dfrom $R_1$ by rotating it by $90^\circ$, $180^\circ$ and $270^\circ$. So it is enough to investigate $R_1$.

The boundedness near $(0,0)$ in $R_1$ is equivalent to the existence of $x_0>0$ and $L>0$ such that for every $0<x<x_0$, we have
$|G(x,t)|=\left|\frac{P(x,xt)}{Q(x,xt)}\right|\le L$ on $[-1,1]$. Let us consider $G(x,t)$ as a rational function of $t\in[-1,1]$ with coefficients in $\mathbb Q(x)$.

*Step 1:* Find the GCD of $P(x,xt)$ and $Q(x,xt)$ in $\mathbb Q(x)[t]$ and divide by it (Euclidean algorithm). The result will be the quotient of two polynomials $P'(x,t)$ and $Q'(x,t)$ of the variable $t$ with coefficients in $\mathbb Q(x)$ such that *they have no common roots* on $[-1,1]$ for sufficiently small $x>0$.

*Step 2:* Check that $Q'(x,t)$ has no roots on $[-1,1]$ for sufficiently small $x>0$. It can be done using the Sturm algorithm in $t$. Note that the values of the corresponding polynomials at $\pm 1$ are rational functions in $x$, so their signs stabilize as $x\to 0$ (to the sign of the ratio of the coefficients at the lowest powers of $x$ in the numerator and the denominator).

*Step 3:* Check that $Q'(x,t)\pm \ell P'(x,t)$ has no roots for fixed small $\ell>0$ and $x\to 0$. It is Sturm again, but now we need to work with coefficients in $\mathbb Q(x,\ell)$. Fortunately, if we have the ratio of two polynomials $\frac{A(x,\ell)}{B(x,\ell)}$, we can say that the sign of this ratio for sufficiently small $\ell$ and $x\to 0$ is that of the ratio of the lowest power terms in $A$ and $B$ in the lexicographic order (the powers of $x$ being compared first).

Unfortunately, while this looks perfect in theory, in practice the arithmetic in the field of rational functions of two variables results in doubling the degree for almost any single addition or multiplication resulting in the exponential (in the degree of the initial rational function) space and time needed to execute this algorithm as written above. My attempts to implement even the initial stages resulted in integer overflow on the first run of the Euclidean algorithm, so some taming of those exponents is
needed if you really want to implement this idea. Or, perhaps, one can come with a better alternative. I hope that people using CAS on the everyday basis will step forward and say something clever now :-)